# Javascript closures and callbacks - variable value doesn't persist after the callback

Tags: javascript, callback, closures

I'm wondering why the variable is undefined if it's initialized within a callback function.

Pseudo code:

```
var name;

//callback function:
function(givenName) {
 name = givenName;

}

alert(name) // undefined
```

The callback function is called from a different module that passes the givenName, and within the callback function name is defined as it should, but not outside the callback function. I'm curious to know how this works and how to get around it. Any articles or answers are more than welcome! thanks.

Comment: is this done using nodejs?

Comment: hi, no, backbone and marionette

Comment: this is not your full code, hard to see whats wrong. so just to make it work, your alert(name) need to be in a function itself.

Comment: callback function is executed asynchronously, and name variable is used in some other part of the code. It seems that the callback is not finished when the name variable is accessed. How can I make sure that the callback function is fully done (async), before proceeding with my app execution?

Answer (score 0):

When this function is called from another context and you want to affect variables in the actual scope you will need to pass the context when calling this method.

Therefore you should use [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) and pass the desired context as first parameter.

Hope this helps